# My Ubuntu doesn't hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My Ubuntu 13.10 installation does not hibernate, no matter what I do. Although I have Tuxonice and enough swap space to cover the real RAM, it still doesn't work.

Is the problem specific to Ubuntu or to the machine? If it's the former, I'd try to install a different Linux dist, otherwise I'd give up.

**Update:** VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

I have 50% of free RAM.

There is no problem suspending the machine.

I have tried all the tips on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/basic-pm-debugging.txt.

Comment: Note you also need enough free RAM to create the image, I've added a few paragraphs to my answer about this.

Comment: Please give us some info on your hardware, including your graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting this in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sync
echo shutdown > /sys/power/disk
echo disk > /sys/power/state
```

and run it as root (`su root`, for which you need a root password, you may also be able to use `sudo -i` with your own password).  I've noticed with, e.g., KDE, that the various shutdown options do not all work for me as an unprivileged user.

If that doesn't work there is probably something wrong with the kernel ACPI module(s) in relation to your hardware.

Note, however, that **you also need enough RAM to create the hibernation image,** not just swap.  Otherwise, you will fail with a "not enough free memory" error.  If that happens, try adding:

```
echo 0 > /sys/power/image_size
```

To the top of that script.  To see the current image size, use `cat /sys/power/image_size`.  This is the maximum size of the image, but if set to zero, it will be as small as possible (presumably the kernel opts to minimalize compression, so it prefers larger images if allowed).

To check what suspend states are available on your hardware:

```
cat /sys/power/state
```

You should see a short list including at least `standby mem disk`.  Documentation for this stuff is in [`[kernel src]/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-power`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-power).

Comment: The script outputs the error "echo: write error: Device or resource busy" with or without the last line.

Comment: Try running each command individually to see which one fails.  Also have a look at `cat /sys/power/state` (I've added a few more paragraphs about that).